# How do i bind an object to the exact position of the mouse?

Tags: c#, mouse

How do i bind an Object to the exact position of the mouse, because if u bind something to the mouse it is not binding the center of the object.

Answer (score 2):

X = mouse.x - (obj.width/2)
Y = mouse.y - (obj.height/2)

usually the position of an object is represented by the position of its top-left corner...

Comment: How do i do this in the Xaml? Withouth touching the Program.cs code?

Comment: you don't ... you could write a converter, but that would have to be a class which would consist of .net code ... in pure xaml? i can't think of any pure xaml solution right now...